# How strong is the field of a magnetic strip on a credit card?

Tags: magnetics

How strong is the field of a magnetic strip on a credit card? In other words, at the typical distance of a read head, say 0.001" how strong is the magnetic field from the stripe?

(Note this is NOT a question about how strong a field is needed to erase the stripe. I already know that. It is how strong the field is that is created by the stripe.)

Comment: I think the key word is retentivity. Not able to find something solid on this.

Comment: Lack of data may have to do with the fact that the cards age and the readers must be periodically cleaned/replaced.  Engineers likely have to simply make the read heads as sensitive and error correcting as possible and the strips retentive as possible.  The initial strength would matter very little compared to the strength after one year of abrasion and moderate proximity to fields.